# OpenCV 2.3 SURF keypoint octave is never equal to 0

Tags: c++, c, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working with OpenCV SURF implementation.

I have found that keypoints, that are obtained by using if the `SurfFeatureDetector` with default parameters never found at octave 0 independently of the image.

Can somebody explain this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the following function (it called from `SURF::operator()` in surf.cpp):

```
static int getPointOctave(const CvSURFPoint& kpt, const CvSURFParams& params)
{
    int octave = 0, layer = 0, best_octave = 0;
    float min_diff = FLT_MAX;
    for( octave = 1; octave < params.nOctaves; octave++ ) <---- octave counter starts from 1
        for( layer = 0; layer < params.nOctaveLayers; layer++ )
        {
            float diff = std::abs(kpt.size - (float)((HAAR_SIZE0 + HAAR_SIZE_INC*layer) << octave));
            if( min_diff > diff )
            {
                min_diff = diff;
                best_octave = octave;
                if( min_diff == 0 )
                return best_octave;
        }
    }
    return best_octave;
}
```

At the code that is written above, we can see that `octave` counter starts from `1`. In accordance to the initialization of `min_diff = FLT_MAX`, the `diff` variable is obviously less than `min_diff`.

So, in case of `nOctaves > 1`, result `best_octave` will never be `0` even if we actually found keypoint at octave `0`.

**EDIT**: This issue is fixed in the next release of the OpenCV (2.4)